# What is the time complexity of tree traversal?

Tags: tree, time-complexity, tree-traversal

What is the time complexity of tree traversal, I'm sure it must be obvious but my poor brain can not work it out right now.

Comment: It's linear Art of Programming Vol 1 page 326

Comment: Is that Knuth's The art of computer programming? I'm trying to find this to give a friend a good example that for an n-ary tree it's linear.

Comment: yes Knuth's "The Art of Computer Programming"

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It depends what kind of traversal you are performing and the algorithm, but typically it would be O(n) where n is the total number of nodes in the tree. The canonical recursive implementation of depth first traversal, will consume memory (on the stack) in the order of the deepest level, which on a balanced tree it would be log(n).

Comment: Is this true of an n-ary tree? I have a data structure that is a tree of max-depth 4 and to traverse it my friend is using 3 for loops, and is saying his algorithm runs in `O(n^3)` time, but I believe it's running in `n` time, `n` being to total number of nodes in the tree

Comment: @Nocholas, you are correct and your friend is wrong. It is O(n).

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't that just be *n* for a tree with *n* nodes?

You visit each tree-leave once, don't you? So i'd say it is linear.

Comment: I guess it should be tree with "n nodes" and not "n leaves".

Comment: @Nanne With the right algorithm it's indeed a linear complexity in time (visiting each node once), but it might still not have a linear complexity in space. Like using the stack.

Comment: But the question was about time complexity.